# Is the term “donor” appropriate to refer to a machine used for parts?

Tags: word-usage

For example, I am intending to purchase an iCloud locked phone to use for parts. Would calling the phone a “donor” be appropriate in such a context?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is perfectly normal usage across wide areas of the US.

> A donor car is effectively a vehicle that is bought to plunder for parts to use towards a kit car project. Depending on what parts are included with the kit, important parts such as the engine, running gear and chassis may be needed, as well as smaller detailing parts such as trim, brightwork, interior and wheels.
>
> https://www.google.com/search?q=%22donor+car%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=%22donor+car%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.13083j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

I would add that is normally used in the context of a specific project. And it normally means there are several parts or a major assembly to be pilfered.

An electronics example "donor computer" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9RJ_RK9WQ4

Comment: I think in the UK it would be more usual to say you "bought it for spares" or "got it for spares", but it's an obvious metaphor.

Comment: Buying for spares implies you don't know which parts you need, just that you expect to need some in the future. Donors are purchased to supply a specific need. You normally spend a good bit of time and effort assessing the donor to ensure it has everything you need and the quality is adequate.

Comment: In the UK rail industry, sometimes a locomotive or other piece of equipment such as a coach or wagon that needs repair is instead kept for spares, especially if the fleet is aging and parts are hard to find. Such a donor item is often called a 'Christmas tree'.

Comment: @Stuart F It's true that, when describing a car (or any other complex product) which has been acquired for its componenrs it is referred to as "having been bought for spares". However when talking about that product or parts derived ftom that product it would be common to refer to it as "the donor vehicle (or computer or wahing machine". For instance we might say "The donor vehicle was written off after a crash but it had only done 8000 miles so the engine was in very good condition. The recipient vehicle had done 150000 miles so the ngine from the donor car was in far better condition.

Comment: Obtaining parts from another vehicle is called cannibalization.

Comment: @Xanne true, but it is also used differently than donor, parts machine, hangar queen, Christmas tree, cabbaging, and so forth. Cannabilizing is done from an operationally equal piece of equipment, at least on paper. If you have two vehicles in your fleet down for different reasons, and intend to return both of them to service, you can cannibalize one to fix the other and then fix the first one when all the needed parts arrive. I wouldn't call what the op is doing cannibalization.

Comment: BTW I started the reopen campaign. I checked several online dictionaries and genref sources and got a big fat zero. This usage has been entirely overlooked. Wikipedia has "More broadly, the term is used to refer to any entity that serves as the source of something transferred to a different entity, including - in scientific fields - the source of matter or energy passed from one object to another.", but we don't like Wikipedia.